# Send email form and get response in android

Tags: android, xml, email

I need to send a form (designed in android xml) as email and get response as well but no idea how !

any body please guide me ....

Thanks

Comment: You Can show the UI of the Xml by activity on any device and programmatically take the screen capture and can send it as attached mail.

Comment: How do you want to send email, using custom email configured through your app or through device email client?

Comment: i want to send a form designed in android xml so that when user opens the mail that form appear and in that form there are some questions for the user, the user respond to those questions e.g yes or no and click on submit then the user response should be send back to the sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Webservice.

Basically just send your data to the webservice endpoint. 
Use your Webservice to send the email.

Comment: i am a beginner in android and don't have any idea of web service could you please explain ... thanks